# Make Docker container only be accessible from specific IPs/IP-Subnet

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I set up a simple container which starts a web application using `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: app/app:latest
    ports:
    - "8000:80"
```

This application can now be accessed from everywhere(!) using `http://server_ip:8000`.

How can I restrict the app only to be accessed from a chosen subnet, for e.g. `123.123.0.0/16`? I tried to add the port to the given zone with `firewall-cmd` but these rules do not apply to Docker containers since Docker itself writes Iptable rules.

Unfortunately, this didn't work:

```
ports:
- "123.123.0.0/16:8000:80"
```

Comment: Does the host itself have multiple interfaces?  If it does you can use the corresponding IP address of the host in `ports:`; if not then you need to make `iptables` or something similar do it for you.

Comment: The Host, i.e. the machine which runs the container has multiple interfaces, yes. To which IP should I refer? Using localhost does not fix the problem - the port "gets opened to the world".

Comment: If the host has interfaces `123.123.45.67` and `10.20.30.40`, use the IP address from the interface that's on that subnet you want to listen on.